# Running Unity on Ubuntu 14.04 returns me to the Ubuntu login screen and never lets me run Unity. Has anyone else had this problem?

Tags: 14.04, unity, login

Whenever I try to run Unity from the terminal in Ubuntu 14.04, I get forced into the Ubuntu login screen to log into Ubuntu again. I used

`sudo apt-get $unity`

and then ran `unity` and this happened. I also removed Unity after this and tried installing it from the Software section and then running, but I still get the same result. Clearly, I have exhausted all my options.. If anyone out there is into Unity and has Ubuntu 14.04, is there something I can do differently to solve this problem?

Comment: Do you have the `ubuntu-desktop` package installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go into whatever terminal you are using and,
Run "sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade" then "sudo apt-get unity ubuntu-desktop" then sudo apt-get install -f" to fix dependencies. 
Then reboot.

Comment: I did all of this and I am still getting the same thing happening.

Comment: Did you leave the dollar sign on 'sudo apt-get install $unity' ? It shouldn't be there. that's used to call a variable. It should read 'sudo apt-get install unity' without the $

Comment: I tried this and I am getting the same result as before. I also just lost 100 more hair follicles.

Comment: You say you went into the software section and installed it. Are you using a GUI, or are you using command line interface only? If so what GUI?